# How to animate 2 css layouts from left to right or from right to left with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

My jQuery level is amateur, and now I try hard to solve this problem with slideshow, I know how to make fadeout or fadein working with variables but I cant animate from left to right or from right to left 2 different layouts with next properties:

1.First layout is an active layout, `display:block`;
2.Second layout ( the slide/layout to show up at next button push but in the same time to remove the first layout) is not an active slide, `display:none`;

Here I get stuck:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.addClass('active-slide');
});
```

Image attached for visibility:
[image](http://postimg.org/image/c63qq7ok7/)

Site link for more information:
[Website](http://www.sorfilm.byethost8.com)

Comment: show us your html and styles

Comment: Are you wanting to slide the image with a fade out or just move the items within a large div?

Comment: [link]http://sorfilm.byethost8.com/ for more information I attached the link page. move the items within a large div but 2 different layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
Add a inner div, like:

```
<div class="slide1">
    <div class="slide-inner">
        ......
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-inner {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var select = jQuery('.slide1').find('.slide-inner > div');
    select.each(function(index) {
      totalWidth = +(totalWidth)+(+$(this).outerWidth(true));   
    });

    jQuery('.slide-inner').width(totalWidth);

    $('.next').click(function(){
        var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
        //currentSlide.removeClass('active-slide');
        //nextSlide.addClass('active-slide');

        // .position() uses position relative to the offset parent, 
        var pos = nextSlide.position();

        // .outerWidth() takes into account border and padding.
        var width = nextSlide.outerWidth();

        //show the menu directly over the placeholder
        jQuery('.slide-inner').animate({"left":(pos.left + width) + "px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work man, maybe you can help me with a visual example on fiddle. Thanks